# C FILE * with no value and no error

Tags: c, file-io

I got a small problem with reading in a file. Code down below. I tried this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_error_handling.htm to check for errors but there aren't any. The file is in the correct location and has the correct name.

When i try to open it it has a value of 1 and all members of the structure have the following value "Unable to read memory"

any ideas?

```
struct node * fileToLinkedList(char * filename) {
    FILE * inputFile;
    inputFile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (inputFile =! NULL) {
        struct program * programPTR;
        struct node * listStart = NULL;
        while ((programPTR = getProgramFromFile(inputFile)) != NULL)
            addProgramToList(&listStart, programPTR);
        fclose(inputFile);
        return listStart;
    }
    else {
        errorMessage("File error", "Error opening the file for reading the TV guide", 0);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly has a value of 1? What are `struct program` and `struct node`? What are the members of the structures? Are you saying the structure members' value is the string "Unable to read memory"? Please update the question to show your actual code; what you've posted will not compile (you have `=!` rather than `!=`) -- unless you're ignoring a compiler warning.

Comment: this line: 'if (inputFile =! NULL) {' results in an assignment statement of 'inputFile = !NULL'  which results in 'inputFile = 1'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
inputFile =! NULL
```

That should be:

```
inputFile != NULL
```

Comment: and that, BTW, should at the very least produce some warning with a decent compiler... check your compiler flags.

Comment: @YoshiPeters why would you turn them off, is there a good reason?

Comment: Was that a rhetorical question? :D